# How to pass the value of xy coordinates to another method in another class in javafx

Tags: javafx, parameter-passing, mouseevent, pass-by-reference, event-listener

I have a pane that has a setOnMouseMoved event listener to get a coordinates of the mouse when the mouse is moving around on that pane.

```
// getting mouse coordinates
private void setMouseMoved() {

    setOnMouseMoved((MouseEvent event) -> {

        double x = event.getX();
        double y = event.getY();

    });
}
```

Is there a way I can pass the x & y values to another method in another class directly? or creating a method to return them as doubles in this class and then passing on to another method in another class?

Comment: Keep a reference to the class that you would like to pass it to call a method from that class

Comment: I can pass the method but am unable to return the value as it's in an evenlistener. Any tips on how to return the value? Can you provide and example? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean return the value?

Comment: return x and y so I can use it in other methods

Comment: dont return it, just call a method and pass in x and y as parameters

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to keep a reference to the class that has the method that you would like to pass in x and y in the class that you have the mouse moved event, and then call the method on the reference of the class and pass in x and y as arguements.

Heres an example.

Say we have class DoSomething that contains a method doSomethingWithXandY that you would like to call from the mouse moved event.

So create the class with a method that takes x and y as parameters like this:

```
     public class DoSomething{
     public void doSomethingWithXandY(double x,double y)
     {
      //put your code here that uses x and y
      System.out.println("x is " + x + " y is " + y);
     }
     }
```

Now in the mouse moved event call this method from a reference of the class like this:

```
        setOnMouseMoved((MouseEvent event) -> {

    double x = event.getX();
    double y = event.getY();
    //create a instance of the class or use an existing one
    DoSomething something = new DoSomething();
    //now call this method
    something.doSomethingWithXandY(x,y);
});
```

Comment: @GeorgeWang I updated my answer above, please have a look and if it is correct please upvote and mark as answered. Thanks!